# superfish - How to disable the top level links

Tags: jquery, superfish

I use superfish Menu Plugin - v1.7.4 
and I want to disable the links of the top level.

I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  // does not work 1:
  $('div#block_top_menu > ul.sf-menu > li > a.sf-with-ul').bind('click', false); // only direct children  

  // does not work 2:
  $('div#block_top_menu > ul.sf-menu > li > a.sf-with-ul').attr("href", "#"); // disable top-level links by replacing with #s

  // does not work 3:      
  $('div#block_top_menu > ul.sf-menu > li > a.sf-with-ul').click(function(){
            return false; // disable browser default when link is clicked
  })

});
```

- 1 - suggested by - https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/275383-solved-disabling-parent-category-links-in-top-menu/
- 2 - suggested by - https://www.mojoportal.com/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=5&mid=34&ItemID=4&thread=5910&pagenumber=1
- 3 - suggested by - https://forum.jquery.com/topic/superfish-menu-how-to-disable-link-at-top-level

but none of them helped.

Probably all related to elder versions of superfish or to other plugins.

so, How can I disable the top level links?

Comment: would be nice to see a demo page with the particular menu you need the links disabled

Comment: probably calling your code before menu has been initialized. The class `sf-with-ul` is added internally within the plugin. If you aren't able to run your code after menu is initialized will need to modify your selectors

Comment: is there a better code than $('div#block_top_menu > ul > li > a').attr("href", "#");  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use

```
$('div#block_top_menu > ul > li > a').attr("href", "#");
```

as @charlietfl advised: sf* classes are added later so I cannot use them in the selector...

Answer (score -1):

Personally, for me this method always work:

HTML:

```
<a href="mylink.php" id="mylink">Link here</a>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#test').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
         e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default behavior
         return false;
    });
});
```

Method first unbinds any click method and then binds our method.

Comment: it seems that superfish does not use click events

Comment: That may be true but you still can unbind any click event if there exists and bind your event which prevent default behaviour and disables click.

Comment: OP's issue has nothing to do with unbinding listeners